# Auto login after boot on OpenBSD

Tags: openbsd

I know I can create an "auto login with a user" function on an OpenBSD desktop (using the default FVWM2 as WM) with:

```
pkg_add slim

-----
start-stop script

# vi /etc/slim 

#!/bin/sh
#
# /etc/rc.d/slim: start/stop slim
#

case $1 in
start)
    /usr/local/bin/slim -d
    ;;
stop)
    kilall /usr/local/bin/slim
    ;;
restart)
    $0 stop
    sleep 6
    $0 start
    ;;
*)
    echo "usage: $0 [start|stop|restart]"

esac

-----
Start at boot & make it executable

# echo "/etc/slim start" >> /etc/rc.local
# chmod +x /etc/slim

-----
Start fvwm after slim is ok

# vi /home/user/.xinitrc

/usr/X11R6/bin/fvwm

-----
Auto-login the UNIX user "user"

# vi /etc/slim.conf

default_user user
auto_login yes
```

**Question:** But this consumes too much space.. are there any other usable options than to install a login manager??

Comment: xdm has no auto-login functionality, you'll have to use another display manager(like the example you posted).

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do it is probably to either:

1. Add `su - <user>` to `/etc/rc.local`

or,

2. Replace getty with a shell instead.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is are you wanting to login using X? If not are you logging on a new (virtual) terminal or the console? If you are wanting to do a network login automatically, I will not be party to such insanity.

Let's start by looking at X. there are two general ways to start X, either a display manager or a script. Most (but not all) display managers have autolog options (consult your display manager's documentation for details. Scripting is complicated by xauth and other details, but can be greatly simplified by the use of startx or xinit. Unfortunately, this assumes that you have already logged in first. This can be addressed by the solutions in the next part of the answer, with the addition of a post login script)

If you are not using X, or just not starting it yet, you can of course us su in init scripts or the like, but this does not setup everything needed for job control, and ties up your console, So I would look hard at getty. There are a large number of getty implementations and replacements. the two I would look at for your use case are mgetty for anything involving serial lines or modems and runtty for all auto login problems not involving a serial line. mgetty  has a large number of options for every conceivable use case involving a serial line. runtty is a special case getty for those times you do not want to call login.

Answer (score 0):

On X is possible with kdm,and probably(never tested) with gdm.
If you want an autologin by shell,can do

```
su - user
```

In rc.local